# Cmake Error "Could not find a package configuration file provided by "moveit" with any of the following names:"

Tags: ros, moveit, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo everybody, I am new here and have already looked for similiar questions but those solutions didnt fix mine.
So my Programm is based on the moveit UR5 tutorial. Now i wanted to move the robot via a node and fix goal position. But the code is not compiling anymore throwing that error. I cant upload an image (> 5 points required) ?? So i copied the terminal.
I am running Ros noetic and moveit 1.

I have isntall moviet with "Sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-moveit" and also tried is over source. None work.
I hope anybody has an idea
Thanks already

Terminal:

```
Could NOT find moveit (missing: moveit_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'moveit'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "moveit" with any
  of the following names:

    moveitConfig.cmake
    moveit-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "moveit" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "moveit_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "moveit"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  BAC/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378054/cmake-error-%22could-not-find-a-package-configuration-file-provided-by-%22moveit%22-with-any---of-the-following-names:%22/) by [mr18b082](https://answers.ros.org/users/74323/mr18b082/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-05-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-05-11**:
Try `catkin clean -y && catkin build`, otherwise uninstall and reinstall according to the tutorial instructions.

**Comment by [mr18b082](https://answers.ros.org/users/74323/mr18b082/) on 2021-05-11**:
catkin clean didnt work because i cant install catkin_tools (tried all kinds of installation variations) and uninstall and reinstall didnt work either

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-05-11**:
Sounds like you should fix your catkin_tools installation first. What are you doing for your install and how does it fail? Please add relevant links and details to your question.

**Comment by [mr18b082](https://answers.ros.org/users/74323/mr18b082/) on 2021-05-12**:
I have installed catkin_tools like this awnser propsed https://answers.ros.org/question/353113/catkin-build-in-ubuntu-2004-noetic/
After trying catkin build this msg comes: "bash: /usr/local/bin/catkin: No such file or directory" I Have catkin installed and catkin_make works and the WS path is added to the bashrc, if that helps.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-05-12**:
That sounds like your `catkin_tools` install was not successful. Cleaning and rebuilding your workspace from scratch (which often solves problems with packages not being linked or found) can also be done with `catkin_make` (was it `catkin_make clean`?), but if you can't run `catkin`, it sounds like your installations might be in disarray and moveit might not be installed correctly either. Has the tutorial worked on your machine before?

**Comment by [mr18b082](https://answers.ros.org/users/74323/mr18b082/) on 2021-05-13**:
Yeah that's the weird part everything worked fine. If I restore a backup it works aswell.
I am going to try out a fanuc tutorial see if that works.

**Comment by [mr18b082](https://answers.ros.org/users/74323/mr18b082/) on 2021-05-13**:
I fixed it! i was missing a specific line in the cmake.. my bad but thanks for your help appreciate it al ot!!

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-05-13**:
Instead of closing the question, please post an answer and specify which line you forgot in your CMakeLists.txt, so the next person who has this problem will know what to do.

**Comment by [mr18b082](https://answers.ros.org/users/74323/mr18b082/) on 2021-05-13**:
Oh sorry didnt know, but i cant reopen (<200 points required)

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-05-13**:
I see, my bad. I just reopened it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I just missed to add the packages to my cmake and package.xml.
moveit_ros_planning
moveit_ros_planning_interface

---

Originally posted by [mr18b082](https://answers.ros.org/users/74323/mr18b082/) with karma: 16 on 2021-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0